# How can this class be used and assigned in this manner?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am currently trying to understand Singly linked lists.

I don't understand some of the code in the SinglyLinkedList.java class. How can the Node class be called and then assigned like: private Node first;

I would have thought that you would have to do something like this

```
 Node<T> help =new Node<>();

 help = first;
```

If someone could explain, or provide me to a link that would help me, it would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

```
public class Node<T> {

    public T elem;
    public Node<T> next;

    public Node(T elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(T elem, Node<T> next) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node{" + "elem=" + elem + '}';
    }

}
```

```java
package list;

/**
 *
 * @author dcarr
 */
public class SinglyLinkedList<T> implements List<T> {

    private Node<T> first;
    private Node<T> last;

    public SinglyLinkedList() {
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        if (isEmpty()){
            return 0;
        } else {
            int size = 1;
            Node<T> current = first;
            while(current.next != null){
                current = current.next;
                size++;
            }
            return size;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T first() {
        return first.elem;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(T elem) {
        // if there is nothing in the list
        if (isEmpty()){
            first = new Node<>(elem);
            last = first;
        // if the list has elements already
        } else {
            // the new element will be the next of what was the last element
            last.next = new Node<>(elem);
            last = last.next; 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(T elem) {
        if (!isEmpty()){
            int index = 0;
            Node<T> current = first;
            while (current != null && current.elem != elem){
                current= current.next;
                index++;
            }
            remove(index);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (isEmpty()){
            return "Empty List";
        } else {
            String str = first.elem.toString() + " ";
            Node<T> current = first;
            while(current.next != null){
                current = current.next;
                str += current.elem.toString() + " ";

            }
            return str;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insertAt(int index, T e) {

        if (index == 0){
            first = new Node<>(e, first);
            if (last == null){
                last = first;
            }
            return;
        }
        Node<T> pred = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) {
           pred = pred.next;
        }
        pred.next = new Node<>(e, pred.next);
        System.out.println(pred);

        if (pred.next.next == null){
            // what does this mean pred.next is?
            last = pred.next;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size()){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } else if (isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

        if (index == 0){
            first = first.next;
            if (first == null){
                last = null;
            }
            return;
        }
        Node<T> pred = first;
        for (int i = 1; i <= index-1; i++) {
            pred = pred.next;
        }
        // remove pred.next
        pred.next = pred.next.next;
        if (pred.next == null){
            last = pred;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no assignment in the highlighted line. That variable does not hold a value, but since it is a class member it's automatically initialized to `null` by the JVM. Also, your question is very unclear to me.

Comment: Where is the rest of the SinglyLinkedList class?

Comment: Dont you miss an add(Node<T>) into SinglyLinkedList?

Comment: Is this the full class?  Looks like its missing members.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster I have edited my original post

Comment: @BackSlash my question is, how can Node class to used like this in the SinglyLinkedList class. I have not seen this before.
To me, the class is being utilized in a similar fashion as an int or String, which I didn't think was possible

Comment: How can Node class to used like **what** in the SinglyLinkedList class? "To me, the class is being utilized in a similar fashion as an int or String": how on earth did you arrive at that conclusion? Ints and strings can be used with the `+` operator. There's none of that going on with Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `first` field is automatically initialized to `null`:

```
private Node<T> first;
```

I assume there will be some method to add an element at the end like so:

```
public void add(T element) {
   if (first == null) {
       first = new Node<T>(element);
       last = first;
   }
   else {
       last.next = new Node<>(element);
       last = last.next;
   }
}
```

So when you create a new SinglyLinkedList:

```
SinglyLinkedList<String> sillyList = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
```

The `first` and `last` fields both hold a null reference.

Note that the `first` method will cause a NullPointerException at this point. A better implementation would be:

```
@Override
public Optional<T> first() {
    if (first != null) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(first.elem);
    }
    else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Now if you add an element:

```
sillyList.add("Adam");
```

The code executed in the `add` method is:

```
first = new Node<>(elem);
last = first;
```

So `first` points to a new Node instance with an `elem` field holding the value "Adam". And `last` points to that same Node instance.

Some of the methods in this class I would implement differently, for example:

```
@Override
public void remove(int index) {     
    if (index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index cannot be negative");
    }
    else if (index == 0 && first != null) {
        first = null;
        last = null;            
    }        
    else {
        Node<T> curr = new Node<>("dummy", first);
        int c = 0;
        while (curr.next != null) {                 
            if (c == index) {
                curr.next = curr.next.next;
                if (curr.next == null) {
                    last = curr;
                }
                return;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
            c++;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.valueOf(c));

}
```

Also, some of the methods don't actually exist in the java.util.List interface, like insert, insertAt and first. So these methods must not have the @Override annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the help.